# Calculated Column not showing appropriately on Mobile

Tags: calculated-column, url, mobile, mobile-view

I created a **Calculated Column** for a contact list which will create a URL to open the contacts Address in Google Maps. It works perfectly on a desktop browser and while requesting a desktop site while on a mobile phone. However, when I use the **SharePoint app** or **Mobile View in a browser (on mobile)** it will show the code and not create a clickable link. The primary use for this is an easy way to go to a clients address on mobile.

```
="<a target=_blank href='https://www.google.com/maps/place/"&[Address]&",+"&[City]&",+"&[State/Province]&"+"&[ZIP/Postal Code]&"'>"&[First Name]&" "&[Last Name]&" Address</a>"
```

Do you know if this may be a limitation of my mobile device, my code, or SharePoint itself?

**Additional Info:**

- Using SharePoint 2013
- Mobile: Galaxy S6
- Mobile Browser: Google Chrome

I am fairly unexperienced with SharePoint and have done this so far with research and Google, so i apologize if thise is fairly novice or more information is needed.

Comment: No answer from me... FYI The hack of putting HTML/JS in a Calculated Column set to a datatype to anything but text that worked since SP2010, was always a hack, never documented by Microsoft. It works on my phone. It does not work anymore in SharePoints Modern Experiences... but since you say the desktop version works.. you are not displaying the Modern Experience View

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. I checked and verified that Modern Experiences is enabled in the SharePoint Admin Center > Settings > SharePoint List and Libraries Experience > New Experience (auto detect). Do you think it could be displaying because auto detect is using Classic? Is there any way to get a custom url based on field data to be displayed on mobile (either using SharePoint Designer or some other function)?

Comment: I don't know, have some questions as well. Best to ask them on Microsoft own SharePoint Forum: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/bd-p/SharePoint_General